# Display Dataframe as FastAPI output

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Dear Community Members,

I am new to FastAPI and I am trying to display the pandas dataframe as FastAPI output but I am not able to get the desired result. Here is something I am have done:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Request, Form
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="htmlDirectory")

class NameValues(BaseModel):
    Check : str = None

@app.get("/home", response_class = HTMLResponse)
def home(request:Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("introduction.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/displayDF")
async def handle_df(Check: str = Form(...)):
    print("User input : ", Check)

    test_list = [["Joe", 34, "Accounts", 10000], ["Jack", 34, "Chemistry", 20000]]
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=test_list, columns=["Name", "Age", "Dept.", "Salary"])

    return data.to_html()
```

The output displays like below screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to actually get the **output in pandas dataframe format?** Something like below :

[image]

Also, below is the "htmlDirectory" code, if some changes has to be done here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Please enter a string in the space provided</h2>

<form action="/displayDF" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Check">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to display your DataFrame is to generate a new `HTML` page using `Jinja` which will use your DataFrame HTML representation (thanks to `df.to_html()` method).

You can update your function like this example:

```
@app.post("/displayDF")
async def handle_df(request: Request, Check: str = Form(...)):
    print("User input : ", Check)
    test_list = [
        ["Joe", 34, "Accounts", 10000], ["Jack", 34, "Chemistry", 20000]
    ]
    data = pd.DataFrame(
        data=test_list,
        columns=["Name", "Age", "Dept.", "Salary"]
    )
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        'df_representation.html',
        {'request': request, 'data': data.to_html()}
    )
```

**df_representation.html (you've to create this new file under htmlDirectory folder):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>displayDF</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>DataFrame representation:</h2>
<!-- You've to mark your data as safe,
    otherwise it'll be rendered as a string -->
    {{ data|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>displayDF</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>DataFrame representation:</h2>
    <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Dept.</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>Accounts</td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>Chemistry</td>
      <td>20000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to download this output dataframe as excel, just like how we do "data.to_excel" in pandas? I can add a download button to the browser but little confused as how to download the dataframe as excel.